Solve a Differential Equation with a Free Parameter and Integrate for Plotting
I would like to solve the differential equation below (w is a positive unknown parameter) and use the solution to integrate the function (y[x] sin[w x]) over the interval [0, pi].
Please i need your help.
An = 10^-10;
eV = 1.6 10^-19;
d = 0.1;
F = 0.1;
G = 1000;
re = 0.7416 An;
V0 = 4.7446 eV;
bh = 1.6189 An^-1;
ch = 0.17;
M = 70;
A = 2 (ch - 1);
B = ch^2 - 1;
NDSolve[{y''[x] + d y'[x] - 
 V0 bh (A E^(-bh (y[x] - re)) + 4 A ch E^(-2 bh (y[x] - re)) - 
    2 B E^(-2 bh (y[x] - re)) + 9 A ch^2 E^(-3 bh (y[x] - re)) - 
    6 B ch E^(-3 bh (y[x] - re)) + 
    6 A ch^3 E^(-4 bh (y[x] - re)) - 
    12 B ch^2 E^(-4 bh (y[x] - re))) ==  
F Cos[w x] + G Cos[M x]}, y[x], x]
   Plot[Integrate[Evaluate[y[x] /. solution] Sin[w x], {x, 0, \[Pi]}], {w, 0, 10}, PlotRange -> All]


When using NDSolve, you need a range to solve over and you need initial conditions and both are missing.

You have to use ParametricNDSolve if a parameter (here w) is undefined!

@UlrichNeumann for anyvalue of w I tried I keep getting Underflow occurred in computation the numbers used in this ode are crazy looking in size. The whole ode needs to be scaled and normalized for numerical solution. ( I used zero for initial conditions). I wonder what Fortran will do with such numbers.

I tried this: sol = ParametricNDSolve[{y''[x] + d y'[x] -
V0 bh (A E^(-bh (y[x] - re)) + 4 A ch E^(-2 bh (y[x] - re)) -
2 B E^(-2 bh (y[x] - re)) + 9 A ch^2 E^(-3 bh (y[x] - re)) -
6 B ch E^(-3 bh (y[x] - re)) +
6 A ch^3 E^(-4 bh (y[x] - re)) -
12 B ch^2 E^(-4 bh (y[x] - re))) == F Cos[w x] + G Cos[M x],
y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 2}, y[x], {x, 0, Pi}, {w}], Plot[Evaluate[Table[y[x][w] /. sol, {w, 0, 2, 1}]], {x, 0, Pi},
PlotRange -> All]

@Nasser I couldn't reproduce your results in Mathematica v12.2. See my answer

@UlrichNeumann here is a link to the notebook if you like to see. I am on V 14.1

It could be because I rationalized all numbers to be exact? as I was first trying to see if DSolve can solve the ode.

@Nasser Even if I rationalize all parameters I don't get this underflow message, see my modified answer

@UlrichNeumann you are using different IC than what I did. I used zero for IC. OP gave no IC, so I picked y(0)=0,y'(0)=0. You picked y(0)=1,y'(0)=2. If you would try with the IC's I used, I think you will get these underflow messages.

@Nasser Ok got it, I took the ic's which  Moo gave in a comment. With "your" ic's I get the same underflow message!

modified
Try ParametricNDSolveValue
An = 10^-10;
eV = 1.6 10^-19 // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
d = 0.1 // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
F = 0.1 // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
G = 1000;
re = 0.7416 An // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
V0 = 4.7446 eV // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
bh = 1.6189 An^-1 // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
ch = 0.17 // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
M = 70;
A = 2 (ch - 1) // Rationalize[#, 0] &;
B = ch^2 - 1 // Rationalize[#, 0] &;

Y = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[x] + d y'[x] - 
     V0 bh (A E^(-bh (y[x] - re)) + 4 A ch E^(-2 bh (y[x] - re)) - 
        2 B E^(-2 bh (y[x] - re)) + 9 A ch^2 E^(-3 bh (y[x] - re)) - 
        6 B ch E^(-3 bh (y[x] - re)) + 
        6 A ch^3 E^(-4 bh (y[x] - re)) - 
        12 B ch^2 E^(-4 bh (y[x] - re))) == F Cos[w x] + G Cos[M x], 
   y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 2}, y , {x, 0, Pi}, {w}, MaxStepSize -> Pi/70/5]



Plot[NIntegrate[Y[w][x] Sin[w x], {x, 0, \[Pi]}], {w, 0, 10},PlotRange -> All]


Plot3D[ Y[w][x] , {w, 0, 2 } , {x, 0, Pi}, PlotRange -> All,PlotPoints->50]


